# Efficiently finding nearest point along a specific axis in 3D space

Tags: python, spatial

I have been playing with this one for a few days now, and keep running into performance walls.

The data:

- 10s to hundreds of thousands of 3D points
- Points are positive/negative ints and fall on a 3D grid with no overlap
- Will rarely add new points
- Will usually be gapless but gaps are possible

The structure:

- Must be able to efficiently find the nearest neighbours along each axis ("closest point to the left") and *only* that axis.
- Rarely handles inserts or deletes after construction (but must handle them)
- Does not need to handle overlapping points

I have found a possible solution in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.html, however the K-d tree seems to be extremely wasteful for this type of data (suitable more for clusters of arbitrary points) and tuned for finding points within a radius. The primary use case for this data is often finding (and following) the nearest neighbour point along each.

Example Data (x, y, z):

```
[(4, 3, 0), (4, 4, 0), (5, 3, 0), (3, 3, 0), (4, 3, 1), ...]
```

Possibly my google-fu is failing me and an optimal structure exists already (preferably in Python), but I have not been able to find one.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have an answer for you, but I'm curious as to what you are trying to do that need such varied analysis.

Comment: You're doing this on a plane right? What's wrong with sorting your list by the absolute difference between your chosen point and the other points?

Comment: @burhan It is for a [minecraft](http://minecraft.net) terrain editor library. The existing libraries (ex: [pymclevel](https://github.com/mcedit/pymclevel)) are extremely cluttered and inefficient. This approach aims to support any of the existing world formats by a simple abstraction which breaks it up into a grid of fixed-sized chunks, with the key being efficient traversal of that grid. Without that, there is little point.

Comment: Can we assume you are using a Euclidean metric? I only ask because, if the points are on a grid, sometimes the Manhattan metric is used instead. It's not clear what "the nearest neighbours along each axis" means exactly.

Comment: A bit hard to know how your code works, and what exactly needs to be optimized, but if you seldom change the points, can't you make points objects that keep track of who are their neighbours and then when adding a new point, it finds its closes neighbours and besides remembering these for itself it inserts itself as their closest neighbour in the relevant position. That way the costly process only needs to run once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about constructing 3 KD-trees for x,y,z axes respectively ? 
You need some kind of tree structure anyway IMO.

Comment: kd-tree for the win! Sounds like a perfect data structure for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, finding "nearest to the left" and whatnot would prove tricky as you have say multiple points on x=4., it would then need to find the closes on the other axes.

Will a more simple "closest point" such as the following not work?

```
for n in xrange(len(points)):
   diff = (((x0-points.x[n])**2) + ((y0-points.y[n])**2) + ((z0-points.z[n])**2))**0.5
```

Then just weed out the 'n' with the smallest diff (excluding current point if included).. :/

Comment: You don't need the **0.5 in the end though since as far I understand it's about identifying which point is closest and not the actual distance (and event if you could save time just applying it to the nearest point).

Answer (score 0):

If only the points are counted as nearest if they follow the axis with the other axis' values static e.g. that (1,1,0) would not qualify as nearest to (0,0,0) but (4,0,0) would you could:

```
import numpy as np
#The .T is ofcourse not neccesary here but then you have to fix it below as well.
points = np.asarray( [(4, 3, 0), (4, 4, 0), (5, 3, 0), (3, 3, 0), (4, 3, 1)]).T
#You have still to check thiss for all points just showing for pt 0
on_same_xy = (points[:-1,:].T == points[:-1,0]).all(axis=1)

z_distance =  (points[2,on_same_xy] - points[2,0])
z_distance_up = z_distance[np.where(z_distance > 0)]
if z_distance_up.size == 0:
    up = None
else:
    up = z_distance_up.min()

z_distance_down = z_distance[np.where(z_distance < 0)]
if z_distance_down.size == 0:
    down = None
else:
    down = z_distance_down.max()

print "Z-up-neighbour %s, Z-down-neighbour %s" % (str(up), str(down))
```

Since you have the two first coordinate-values just of points[-1,0] then position of the up-point and down-point as well as distance can be accessed from up and down.

I realize the code got a bit messy, but once a big data-set is inside nunpy it really should work faster. Also, again, it's a question of what your question asks for.